# How to bulk-untag multiple posts?

Tags: posts, taxonomy, bulk

I have multiple batches of posts that are wrongly tagged with some terms, they need those terms to be removed.

Specifically, I have...

- Custom post type: "article"
- Custom taxonomy: "company" (hierarchical)

Let's say I have 42 "articles" tagged with "company" "Widgets Inc".
18 of them should not have been and need to be disassociated.

WordPress' Bulk Edit in the "article" post list is good at helping me *add* terms, but not at removing them.

The expected behavior should be to *uncheck* the wrongly-associated term, but that doesn't seem to be available... when opening Bulk Edit, the term is not checked at all.

Moving/deleting the term from *all* associated posts would not be right as a proportion of the "articles" are properly tagged.

This has to be about disassociating a selectable term from multiple, but not all, associated posts.

Likewise, I do not want to remove *all* "company" terms from the offending posts, because they also have other associated terms which are correct.

Comment: As you've noticed, WordPress does not have a UI for this. Are you looking for a code solution?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Or suitable plugin, etc. Code may be tricky as the number of incorrect associations is as-yet unknown but could be significant in scale. But anything quicker than going to edit or quick-edit individual posts would be useful.

Comment: There's this hack, I suppose - https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/a-gory-hack-for-removing-tags-and-categories-from-multiple-posts/ Can't believe WordPress doesn't have this.